# atos cannot load symbols for the file my.app.dSYM for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I received crash reports from App Review. And then i download the .dSYM from iTunes connect. When I type:

```
$ atos -arch arm64 -o /Users/luckyxmobile/Desktop/dSYMs/6505A7CE-3120-339B-8D05-AC9E24B3EC8F.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Family\Health\Tracker -l  0x1000e0000 0x000000018139c11c
```

There is a error.

```
atos cannot load symbols for the file /Users/luckyxmobile/Desktop/dSYMs/6505A7CE-3120-339B-8D05-AC9E24B3EC8F.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FamilyHealthTracker for architecture arm64.
```

Are those directories wrong? And i don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your app was not compiled for the `arm64` architecture. If you run a `file <path-to-your-dSYM>`, you should see what architecture the app was compiled for. If you pass the right architecture from `file` command's output to the `atos` command, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you lose 1 space bewteen \ and Health and 1 space bewteen \ and Tracker.

```
$ xxx/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Family\ Health\ Tracker -l  0x1000e0000 0x000000018139c11c
```